# Music not muting when I press the GUI button but it will print the volume

Tags: lua, roblox

```
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local mouse = player:GetMouse()
local mutebutton = script.Parent


while true do
    wait()
    local b = game.StarterGui.MusicPlayer.Playlist:GetChildren()
    local c = math.random(1, #b)
    local d = b[c]
    d:Play()
    wait(d.TimeLength)
    
    mutebutton.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
        d.Volume = 0
    end)    
    
end
```

If i was to replace d.Volume = 0 with print(d.Volume) or print("testing") then it will work however when I change it to actually mute the audio, it dosent want to work. Anyone know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem with your script is that the `MouseButton1Click:Connect` (listening for clicks) is done only after the `wait(d.TimeLength)` (after the song has finished playing).

Adding on from ivy's suggestion of using `d:Pause()`, I would suggest doing something like this:

```lua
while true do
    local b = game.StarterGui.MusicPlayer.Playlist:GetChildren()
    local d = b[math.random(1, #b)]
    d:Play()
    
    local connection = mutebutton.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
        if d.IsPaused then -- Makes the pause button a play button if the song is paused already
            d:Resume()
        else
            d:Pause()
        end
    end)    
    
    d.Ended:Wait() -- Wait until music ends
    connection:Disconnect() -- Remove connection (to prevent multiple functions on the same button click)
end
```